# Cannot access restApiId & restApiRootResourceId for cross stack reference in serverless yml

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

Since I had an issue of 200 resource error, I found a way of using cross stack reference by dividing into different services. I managed to do that by using the cross-stack reference. The issue is I cannot give the restApiId & restApiRootResourceId dynamically. Right now, am statically setting ids into the service-2.

Basically the service-1 looks like,

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  apiGateway:
    restApiId: 
      Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
    restApiResources:
      Fn::GetAtt:
          - ApiGatewayRestApi
          - RootResourceId
custom:
  stage: "${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}"

resources:
  Resources:
    ApiGatewayRestApi:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties:
        Name: ${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}-1

  Outputs:
    ApiGatewayRestApiId:
      Value:
        Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
      Export:
        Name: ApiGatewayRestApi-restApiId

    ApiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId:
      Value:
         Fn::GetAtt:
          - ApiGatewayRestApi
          - RootResourceId 
      Export:
        Name: ApiGatewayRestApi-rootResourceId
```

And the service-2 looks like this,

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  apiGateway-shared:
    restApiId:
      'Fn::ImportValue': ApiGatewayRestApi-restApiId
    restApiRootResourceId:
      'Fn::ImportValue': ApiGatewayRestApi-rootResourceId
```

As the above service-2 config, I cannot reference the Ids. 
FYI: Both services are in different files.
So How what's wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Serverless has [special syntax](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-cloudformation-outputs) on how to access stack output variables: `{cf:stackName.outputKey}`. 
Note that using the `Fn::ImportValue` would work inside the `resources` section.